# mysql avg() function in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, average

I have a problem about mysql avg() function, I have a table like below:

```
employee_id      evaluator        score
0001             Peer              5
0001             Peer              8
0001             Student           10
0001             Student           4
0001             Supervisor        5
```

my question is how can I get the average score of the Peer evaluators only, I have already tried many tutorials but have no luck. your answers will be very much appreciated, thank you in advance.

i tried

```
SELECT evaluator,employee_id, AVG(score)
FROM tbl_evaluation
GROUP BY employee_id
HAVING employee_id= '0001' and evaluator='Peer';
```

but does not work

Comment: please show what you tried and explain what went wrong (errors etc) - this isn't a particularly complex thing to do. Making a query using AVG, from VB, should be no different to any other query. Is it the SQL that's causing you problems, or the VB part? Did your query work just in a SQL environment, but not in VB? You haven't explained your problem at all. If you've already found tutorials there is no point us repeating a generic example here, but we could help fix your particular problem, if you can explain it in proper detail.

Comment: `SELECT AVG(score) FROM yourTable WHERE evaluator = 'Peer'`

Comment: for the query only, you can simply do an AVG query but with a WHERE clause restricting the evaluator column (as Tim has shown at the same moment I posted this comment!)

Comment: i tried SELECT `evaluator`,`employee_id`, AVG(`score`)
FROM tbl_evaluation
GROUP BYemployee_id
HAVING  `employee_id`= '0001' and evaluator='Peer'; but dos not work

Comment: i already got it sir, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0):

You should group it by evaluator instead of employee. HTH.

```
SELECT evaluator,employee_id, AVG(score) FROM tbl_evaluation GROUP BY evaluator HAVING employee_id= '0001' and evaluator='Peer';
```